# Moar red comment upvotes

Tags: bug, comments, design, up-votes

The more upvotes a comment has the more red the number gets. But at a specific point the number of upvotes of a comment stops being red.

That is unfair. I vote for more red! No matter how many upvotes.

[image: comment upvotes]

Comment: So red it's grey